# PCB hole metallization

Tags: pcb, jumper, dip

Is it mandatory to metallize the holes for the DIP package on a single-sided printed circuit board?

And is it necessary to metalize the holes for the jumpers if they are on the outside of the conductive pattern?

The document says that it is not recommended to make metallized holes on a single-sided printed circuit board.

The reason I choose to do this on a single-sided PCB is that I have already described everywhere that this is a single-sided printed circuit board in the documentation, to my work. Correspondence of documents will take a lot of time.

[image]

Comment: Don't you need to have some copper on there to be able to solder the DIP legs onto?

Comment: @GooberZoober on veroboard and similar, you just solder to the copper on the plane, but yeah, that's mostly bad.

Comment: @GooberZoober I ask about it!

Comment: If you *don't* do plate-through holes, you should increase pad diameter, otherwise tiny pads tend to easily de-laminate.

Comment: hey, user103... : where on earth can one get single-sided boards made that aren't special purpose (like metal substrate for high-power, or intentionally high-quality single-sided fiberglass board for mass-produced power supply PCBs)? All PCB manufacturers I know don't even charge extra for the second side, and not for metallized holes. This question really only makes sense when you're etching your boards yourself, which, honestly, is a financially, and emotionally, bad choice, I promise. Or, this question makes sense when you make 100000 of your board, but then you should be talking

Comment: to your board house, and not random people on the internet. So, in which context are you asking this?

Comment: @Marcus Müller  I do the theoretical part. How to do the right thing. It is unlikely that I will make this board. There was a misunderstanding when I saw an article that single-sided printed circuit boards do not metallize

Comment: I don’t understand if I should metallize

Comment: you should get a double-sided board, unless you have a very good reason not to. If you have a very good reason, then that probably is important for whether you should metallize or not. You haven't told us your reason why you do a single-sided board, so we can't tell you whether you should metallize your holes.

Comment: @Marcus Müller  The good reason is that, I have already described everywhere that this is a single-sided printed circuit board in the documentation, to my work. Correspondence of documents will take a lot of time.

Comment: bad luck, engineering doesn't care whether you've made bad choices in the past. If you make a bad choice with respect to the number of sides, it also doesn't matter whether you metallize your holes or not. Bad design stays a bad design.

Comment: @Marcus Müller  Thanks for the help. I will think .